# Elasticsearch QueryParsingException count query

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, count

I try to create a function that returns me the count of events with Elasticsearch.

When I run this code it raises at first a `BroadcastShardOperationFailedException` and then a nested `QueryParsingException`.

But somethings wrong with my query but I don't get it what it could be. Here's my query:

```
esclient = Elasticsearch()

countParams['body'] = {}
countParams['body']['query']= {}
countParams['body']['query']['filtered']= {}
countParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']= {}
countParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or']={}

toadd['term'] = {}
toadd['term']['log_device_id']= id["ID"]
countParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or']= toadd
countResponse = esclient.count(index='indexName',
                               doc_type='event',
                               body=countParams)
```

That's only a part of the file but this part wont work and it drives me crazy.

I don't find a documentation to the count func of Elasticsearch.

Edit:

Here the full exception message:

```
GET /indexName/event/_count [status:400 request:0.007s]
TransportError(400, '{"count":0,"_shards":  {"total":5,"successful":0,"failed":5,"failures": [{"index":"IndexName","shard":0,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[logappclient1][0] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[indexName] [filtered] query does not support [term]]; "},{"index":"indexName","shard":1,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[indexName][1] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[indexName] [filtered] query does not support [term]]; "},{"index":"indexName","shard":2,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[indexName][2] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[indexName] [filtered] query does not support [term]]; "},{"index":"indexName","shard":3,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[indexName][3] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[indexName] [filtered] query does not support [term]]; "},{"index":"indexName","shard":4,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[logappclient1][4] ]; nested: QueryParsingException[[indexName] [filtered] query does not support [term]]; "}]}}')
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What happens if you replace `quere` with `query`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, thats a stupid mistake. But nothing changes. The Exception stay the same

Comment: Can you update your question with the full exception you get?

Comment: I edited my question. The full exception is now in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
esclient = Elasticsearch()

countParams = {
   'query': {
      'filtered': {
         'filter': {
           'or': [
              {
                 'term': {
                    'log_device_id': id["ID"]
                 }
              }
           ]
         }
      }
   }
}

countResponse = esclient.count(index='indexName',
                               doc_type='event',
                               body=countParams)
```

Comment: I try this but nothing changed. I become the same error message.

Comment: I just modified, try again please

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for help this is perfect! Thank you very much!